# Convert XMLl to Java object using xstream

Tags: xml, xstream

I have the following xml. How do I convert into a java object using xstream. I tried sevral ways but I end up in getting conversionexception. 
Code is below. I don't have any idea of how to convert to `BookDetails` object.

**XML string:**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
    <Books>
    <bookdetails>
    <bookId>20</bookId>
    <bookName>AAAA</bookName>
    <amount>35</amount>
    </bookdetails>
    </Books>
```

**BookDetails class:**

```
@XStreamAlias("bookDetails")
public class BookDetails {
@XStreamAlias("bookId")
private int bookId;
@XStreamAlias("bookName")
private String bookName;
@XStreamAlias("amount")
private int amount;
//getters and setters
}
```

**Books class:**

```
@XStreamAlias("Books")
public class Books{

@XStreamAlias("bookDetails")
private List<BookDetails> bookDetails=new ArrayList<BookDetails>();
}

--------------unmarshall class method----

public BookDetails convertXml(String xml){

            xstream.processAnnotations(Books.class);
            xstream.processAnnotations(BookDetails.class);
            xstream.addImplicitCollection(Books.class,"BookDetails");
            return (BookDetails)xstream.fromXML(processOrderXML);
}
```

Comment: Please edit your question and include your code that does not work along with exact error you are having.

Comment: Modified the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several issues with your code.

First, you use wrong alias for `BookDetails` class. You are declaring it as `@XStreamAlias("bookDetails")` and your XML tag is all lowercase `bookdetails`.

Then you are using wrong field name for defining implicit collection: it should be `bookDetails` - as your list field name, and not `BookDetails`.

And finally, you have to parse complete XML and then you can get your `BookDetails` data from it. Instead of creating `BookDetails` instance `XStream` will give you `Books` instance.

As additional observation, you don't have to add aliases for fields that have exact name as XML tags.

Corrected code would be:

```
@XStreamAlias("bookdetails")
public class BookDetails
{
    private int bookId;
    private String bookName;
    private int amount;
}

@XStreamAlias("Books")
public class Books
{
    private List<BookDetails> bookDetails = new ArrayList<BookDetails>();
}

public BookDetails convertXml(String xml)
{
    xstream.processAnnotations(Books.class);
    xstream.processAnnotations(BookDetails.class);
    xstream.addImplicitCollection(Books.class, "bookDetails");
    Books b = (Books) xstream.fromXML(xml);
    // and now you can return your BookDetails element (in case you want only first one)
    return b.bookDetails.get(0);
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I got a basic understanding on this.